# Maps out of finite spectra commute with coproducts

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider a finite spectrum $x$ in the homotopy category $\mathcal{F}$ of spectra.

A paper claimed that the hom functor $\left[x, {-}\right]$ commutes with coproducts. But coproducts are not filtered colimits, so this seems not to follow from just the fact that $x$ is compact in $\mathcal{F}$. In this case, why does the functor commute with coproducts? I imagine it follows from some well-known property of finite spectra.

I want to check my understanding as someone with little knowledge of stable homotopy theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coproducts are filtered colimits of finite coproducts, and $[x, -]$ commutes with finite coproducts because spectra have finite biproducts.